# jQuery - Select series of items unless it has a class

Tags: jquery

I want to select series of list items unless it has a class. I want to then hide and show.

```
<ul>
  <li class="parent">Parent</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li class="parent">Parent</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li class="parent">Parent</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('li').not('.parent').hide();
$('li.parent').on('click', function(){
    //select every next siblings unless it finds a classname
});
```

So when parent is clicked i want to show the next two lists.

I know this would be easy with nested lists. But I am do this over a plugin generated code. This is how its structured.

[There's my code.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaJzvv)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`.nextUntil()` method](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) in order to select the `li` siblings until the next `.parent`:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/68o51dwr/)

```
$('li.parent').on('click', function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('.parent').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li').not('.parent').hide();
$('li.parent').on('click', function(){
    $('li').not('.parent').not($(this).nextUntil('li.parent')).hide();
    $(this).nextUntil('li.parent').slideToggle();
});
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/zyqzkb4k/)